# is there a solution for to keep the video title from being truncated?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

Im using a wordpress plugin to embed youtube videos. the youtube video title is truncated. I found there using the following css code at plugin assets

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

I have changed the css to

```
overflow: unset;
text-overflow: unset;
white-space: unset;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

But Still Im getting the same results.

Also changed the css code on minified version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your css like this:

```
body .classname {
    overflow: unset !important;
    text-overflow: unset !important;
    white-space: unset !important;
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
}
```

OR

You can share your url, so that we can find the proper way for it.